# Using an integration factor to integrate

Tags: integration

how would you integrate:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}+\dfrac{2x}{50+t}=6.$$

I've gotten the integrating factor, which is $50+t$, but where do I go from there?

Thank You.

Comment: I would suggest you check your IF. It should be $e^{2\ln(50+t)} = (50+t)^2$

Comment: Did you forget about the $2$ in the numerator?  Deepak is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation is of the form

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+p(t)x = 6.$$

The integrating factor is then $q(t) = \exp(\int p(t) dt)$ (check this as what you've written above is not the correct integrating factor, I'm guessing because you missed a constant in $p(t)$). Once you have $q(t)$, multiply both sides of the equation by it to obtain

$$q(t)\frac{dx}{dt} + p(t)q(t)x = 6q(t).$$

Now note that $\frac{dq}{dt} = p(t)q(t)$ (by design), so we have

$$q(t)\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dq}{dt}x = 6q(t)$$

which can be written as

$$\frac{d}{dt}(q(t)x) = 6q(t)$$

by the product rule. Therefore, $q(t)x = \int 6q(t)dt$ so

$$x = \frac{1}{q(t)}\int 6q(t) dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $e^\int{\frac{2}{50+t}}$ on both sides. The LHS becomes a perfect differential. Integrate on both sides to get
$$ x (50+t)^2  =  6\int{(50+t)^2}$$

Can you carry on from there?

Comment: Yup, it should be 2(50+t) and not (50+t) for the integrating factor.

Comment: No, it should be $(50+t)^2$.

Comment: Doesn't the integral in the index evaluate to the same?

Comment: @L__ I was addressing the comment by user151408 (right above mine). Did you downvote me because of your misunderstanding?

Comment: Oops... my bad. I think I over-reacted anyway! sorry

Answer (score 0):

If the first order linear DE
$$\frac{dx}{dt}+P(t)x=Q(t)$$
has integrating factor $I(t)$ then multiplying both sides by $I(t)$ gives
$$I(t)\frac{dx}{dt}+I(t)P(t)x=I(t)Q(t)\ .$$
This can be written
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigl(I(t)x\bigr)=I(t)Q(t)$$
which is now easy to integrate.  At least, the LHS is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your integrating factor is wrong. It should be $e^{2\ln(50+t)} = (50+t)^2$.

Multiplying throughout by that you get:

$(50+t)^2\frac{dx}{dt} + 2x(50+t) = 6(50+t)^2$

$\frac{d}{dt}[x(50+t)^2] = 6(50+t)^2$

It now becomes a separable d.e. you can easily solve.